# Native JPA query not getting result

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Why isn't this query getting a result?

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE u.email = ?1",
            nativeQuery = true)
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The method is used like this and the result is null:

```
User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
```

The email is definitely in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace `u.*` to `*`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM users u WHERE u.email = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
User findByEmail(String email);
```

See original [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/c2cd87689f26b28c9ca5d1f368821baadc8323c6/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L223).

But in your case I think it's better don't use the native query:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = ?1")
User findByEmail(String email);
```